# Реализация бесконечного цикла в службе Windows

Tags: c#, windows-service

Мне необходимо реализовать бесконечный цикл в службе windows, который ищет по названию процессы и их закрывает. Вставка `while(true){}` в OnStart приводит к неправильному запуску службы. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, т.к. я далеко не профи в этом деле.

Comment: Используйте таймер, как в [туториале](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

Comment: Вы допустили классическую ошибку написания OnStart: в этом методе нельзя запускать никакой тяжёлый код... у вас он не тяжёлый - просто бесконечный. Как правильно - комментарий выше.

Comment: Чтобы написать этот код, не надо быть профи, надо 15 минут почитать документацию. Но здесь очень маловероятно, что код напишут за вас с нуля.

Comment: @AK OnStart вызывается только при старте или периодически после полного его выполнения?

Comment: @aepot Решение действительно было простым, инструкции достаточно.